# Finding the closest pair of keys if lookup fails in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Lets say I have a Python dictionary where the keys are actually integers. I can create one like this:

```
>>> d = dict([(1, 0), (7, 10), (28, 20)])
>>> d
{1: 0, 7: 10, 28: 20}
```

Now, I want to do a look up where if the key is found, its index is returned. This part is really easy, like so:

```
>>> key = 7
>>> d[key]
10
```

If a key is not found, then I  want to return the bound for the keys. For example:

```
>>> key = 6
>>> d[key]
Bound(1, 7)
```

Since 6 does not exist as a key, I am returning the 2 keys between which it lies. **Is such a thing possible to do without basically iterating the entire dictionary?** If not, then this question does not really need to be answered. If this is indeed possible, please include some performance implications as well if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a binary search over a list of tuples would be better for this use-case.

Comment: A custom subclass of `defaultdict` with `__missing__` overriden to return a `Bound` object rather than adding a new item to the `dict` sounds like what you need.

Comment: @chepner but how would the implementation of `__missing__` work without iterating the entire keyset?

Comment: Pretty sure it's not possible without iteration. The only reason dictionary lookup works without needing iteration is because it uses a hash table - but that won't help you find which keys are closest to a given one.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I think it'd be easiest to dump a list of keys, insert the missing, sort and retrieve n-1 & n+1

Comment: In a sense, you have to iterate. However, the subclass can maintain a separate list of intervals between the existing keys, allowing fast lookup of the correct interval.

Comment: @chepner Could you maybe expand on that comment with some code examples in an answer?

Comment: I don't have time to work up an example. But let's say your dict has keys 1, 7, and 28. Your custom dict would keep an list of intervals `[(None, 1), (1, 7), (7, 28), (28, None)]`. `__missing__` would just search that list to find the one that contains your missing key `k`. You would also need to override various other methods (like `__setitem__`, `pop`, etc) to update the list every time a new key is added or deleted. Since the list is sorted, you can use the `bst` module to do the searches in O(lg n) time rather than iterating over the entire list.

Comment: (Modifying the list would still be O(n) operations, so you might want to look at fancier data structures than a simple list.)

Comment: Google "interval trees" for ideas.

Comment: @chepner do you have any in mind? Seems like list of tuples would be one of the few ways of storing intervals. Edit: read other comment now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution using a function to access a normal dict (I used an `OrderedDict` as I have an older version of Python here now, you can use a normal `dict` if you have Python 3.6 or more, as they are ordered.)

We sort the dict by key, which lets us use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html) to find the surrounding keys quickly.

```
import bisect
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict(sorted([(1, 0), (7, 10), (28, 20)])) # Could be a simple dict with Python 3.6+

class Bound:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Bound({}, {})'.format(self.a, self.b)

def closest(key, d):
    try:
        return d[key]
    except KeyError:
        keys = list(d.keys())
        ins_point = bisect.bisect(keys, key)
        return Bound(keys[ins_point-1] if ins_point >= 1 else None,
                     keys[ins_point] if ins_point < len(keys) else None)

closest(7, d)
# 10

closest(8, d)
# Bound(7, 28)

closest(30, d)
# Bound(28, None)

closest(-1, d)
# Bound(None, 1)
```

You can also subclass `dict`, updating the `__missing__` method (code for Python >=3.6, assuming that `dict` is ordered:

```
import bisect

class Bound:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Bound({}, {})'.format(self.a, self.b)


class BoundDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        keys = list(self.keys())
        ins_point = bisect.bisect(keys, key)
        return Bound(keys[ins_point-1] if ins_point >= 1 else None,
                     keys[ins_point] if ins_point < len(keys) else None)


d = BoundDict(sorted([(1, 0), (7, 10), (28, 20)])) 

print(d[7])
# 10

print(d[8])
# Bound(7, 28)

print(d[30])
# Bound(28, None)

print(d[-1])
# Bound(None, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution with custom dict class:

```
import bisect
import collections


class Bound:
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Bound({}, {})'.format(self.left, self.right)


class MyDict(collections.defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.lst = sorted(key for key in self)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self:
            bisect.insort_left(self.lst, key)
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.lst.remove(key)
        super().__delitem__(key)

    def __missing__(self, key):
        right_index = bisect.bisect(self.lst, key)
        left_index = right_index - 1
        right = self.lst[right_index] if right_index != len(self.lst) else None
        left = self.lst[left_index] if left_index != -1 else None
        return Bound(left, right)


d = MyDict([(1, 0), (7, 10), (28, 20)])
print(d[-3]) # Bound(None, 1)
print(d[6]) # Bound(1, 7)
print(d[7]) # 10
print(d[33]) # Bound(28, None)
del d[7]
print(d[6]) # Bound(1, 28)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def bound(x, d):

  if x in d:
    return x
  else:

    for i in sorted(d):
      if x > i:
        l = i

    for j in sorted(d, reverse=True):
      if j > x:
        h = j

    return(l,h)


d = dict([(1, 0), (7, 10), (28, 20), (4,5), (2,5), (15,10)])

bound(17,d)
```

(15, 28)